# Save stored procedure in XSD file

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database that works with `mdb` and I am building a new application and I need that for the time been to work with `mdb` and in the future I will transfer it to `SQL`. The problem is that i want to build something like a store-procedure and it can't be done in visual studio with `mdb` (I am working with xsd-file).

Is there a way to make something like stored procedure and to connect it to `mdb`?

for example: I want to have a stored procedure that has 4 parameters and to be able to check then in the "where".

I didn't see any way of doing that in the xsd-file

Thank`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you can do is build a query with what would be the content of the proposed sp.
Some sort of abstraction, say a Factory pattern based on what sort of backend in use is probaly as good as it gets at the moment.

Comment: If you could be a littel more specific about the second part i will be grateful, one of my problams is the build a query with string parameter,to insert any paramter its ok i got it i am using "?", but what happans when i want to check a string in ntext i cant use "?" or like.

Comment: Don't get you. What do you mean by check a string in ntext, can't see how parameterised query versus sp with parameterised arguments makes a difference

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i solved in a diffrent way. i used LINQ over the DATATABLE and it made my code alot cleaner and nicer.

Comment: Well that's certainly an agnostic solution, nicer, depends though.

Comment: Well aside from me not being a big fan of datatable and dataset, depends on whether it's sucking the lot down and then filtering client side, or building a  query based on the filtering you need.